# How to Print a QRBand on Every Page of a QuickReport?

Tags: delphi, quickreports

I use Delphi2006 and QuickReport4 Components in a Clinical Analysis.

I need to print pages with results of patient's exams.

When I print, I use the `PageHeader` band in blank with a certain height to avoid printing on the paper logo. But when the paper with logo is over, the report enables other band with that same logo.

The problem is that the third Band is the Patient Information Head and it was supposed to appear in every page, but the only band that does it is the Header and Footer.

I've setted up both blank band and information band as `HeaderBand`, but the QuickReport only accepts the first one as a header.

Any ideas of how do I print another band on every page at the top of the page?

I also have this same problem with the doctor signature that should be on every page, but only appears on the last one.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! SO has an extensive tag system which allows users to identify what technology is involved in a question, watch or ignore certain subjects, narrow their searches to a specific area, and even learn about the tag's subject via its wiki.
This tag system works. You can rely on it to notify users who are interested in a tag about your question. You shouldn't put tag information in your subject line. Thanks! :-)

Comment: Ok, I will be more carefull the next times, thanks!

Comment: I just discovered that it is important to retain certain information in the subject line because it becomes more visible by people who are searching about it in google and other search engines. This tag system is fully integrated with those too?

Comment: It's not your task to worry about Google search optimization. :-) Your task is to follow the guidelines when posting here, so that things work like they're designed to work. I've never had an issue with not finding things properly in Google because the title wasn't what I thought it should be, and the important thing is to be able to search **here**. You do that using `[tag]` values in your search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a ChildBand, having the PageHeader as its ParentBand.
Every time your (blank) PageHeader will be printed, her child will also be printed right after it.

Comment: that if I did not have a header with information that should appear even if the blank band was disabled, because of the problem of the pré-printed paper. Even so, thanks for the help!

Comment: Aliás, podias ter respondido em português ou espanhol! :-P